# Jpeg Lossless Compression Using python

Tags: image-compression, lossless-compression

I think for a colored Jpeg image , size of each pixel is not 24bit(8 bit for each r,g,b). Its already stores the pixel intensity value in minimum bits(for intensity value 56 it uses 111000 instead of 00111000). then how Lossless compression is possible in Jpeg images.

Comment: How is this question related to python?

Comment: sorry for the wrong tags.